# Ember 2.7.2 and ember-models-table: A helper named "models-table" could not be found

Tags: ember.js

I install Ember 2.7.2 and I create my first application. I install the addon ember-models-table (ember install ember-models-table).

Template:

```
<h3>Prueba</h3>

{{models-table
    data=model
    columns=columns}}
```

I use "ember server" to test my app. When I go to http://localhost:4200/prueba I see this error in console:

*Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: A helper named "models-table" could not be found*

Any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: which version of ember?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you didn't install this addon correctly for some reason. All I can recommend you is to re-install it by typing these commands:

```
npm uninstall --save ember-models-table
npm prune
rm -rf node_modules tmp
npm cache clean
npm install
ember install ember-models-table
```

If the problem still exists after you re-install the addon, probably something is wrong with your environment, not the `ember` itself.

Comment: When I try to run your first command: The specified command uninstall is invalid. For available options, see `ember help`.

Comment: But I recreate the application and now the error is gone. You were right

Comment: Yeah, instead of the first command you needed to do `npm uninstall --save ember-models-table`, I edit the answer. Glad that everything's ok now!